# Kali-Linux Netstat command not showing ports

Tags: kali-linux, netstat

I've been using the netstat command in a remote desktop running kali and not getting any results.

this is all i get after using netstat

```
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
Active UNIX domain sockets (w/o servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
```

Answer (score 2):

The Kali Linux OS instance you are running either does not have any processes listening on any network ports, or it has no network adapter/NIC available to use to listen for any protocols.

---

### Checking the Network Adapter Status

1. You can check the "status" of any network interface by running the [`nmicli device status`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nmcli) command and view the `STATE` of the interface.

   - A `connected` state listed on an interface means that interface (e.g. `eth0`) is capable of being used to listen for traffic coming in on specific ports.
   - An `unavailable` state listed on an interface (e.g. `eth0`) means that interface is not capable of being used to listen for traffic coming in on specific ports.
2. You can also check the `state` of any network interface by running the [`ip link show`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ip) command and viewing the `state` of the adapter.

   - `state UP` means "connected" (same as #1 above)
   - `state DOWN` means "unavailable" (same as #1 above)

---

### Checking all Ports

If you have network interfaces that are available and capable of accepting incoming traffic, then be extra thorough with checking the ports listening on the system by running [`nmap -sT -sU -p- localhost`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nmap) and scan all ports.

A result of "**All 131010 scanned ports on localhost (127.0.0.1) are closed**" or something to that effect means. . .

1. The server has no processes listening on any ports; or
2. The network interface on the server is unavailable to be used for incoming TCP or UDP traffic

---

### Using `netstat -lpntu` Command

Use the `-lpntu` parameters with the `netstat` command to list the ports that are listening or opened for both TCP and UDP connections on the server.

```
   netstat -lpntu
```

---

### Output

> **Note:** If the server has any processes listening on any ports, then you'll see those in the output (example below). If
>   you get back no records when running this command, then
>   that means exactly that, nothing is listening on any TCP ports nor accepting any UDP traffic on the
>   server.

```
[root@Test123 ~]# netstat -lpntu
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2617/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2724/master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:514             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3043/syslog-ng
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      2617/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      2724/master
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:514             0.0.0.0:*                           3043/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           2437/dhclient
```

---

### Further Resources

- [nmcli(1) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nmcli)
- [ip(8) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ip)
- [nmap(1) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nmap)
- [netstat(8) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat)

  > ```
  > -l, --listening
  > Show only listening sockets. (These are omitted by default.)
  > ```
  >
  > ---
  >
  > ```
  > -p, --program
  > ```
  >
  > Show the PID and name of the program to which each socket belongs.
  >
  > ---
  >
  > **TCP**
  >
  > ```
  > [--tcp|-t]
  > ```
  >
  > **UDP**
  >
  > ```
  > [--udp|-u]
  > ```
  >
  > **Local Address**
  >
  > Address and port number of the local end of the socket. Unless the
  >   `--numeric` (**`-n`**) option is specified, the socket address is
  >   resolved to its canonical host name (FQDN), and the port number is
  >   translated into the corresponding service name.

Comment: hey thanks for the response, I tried this and I'm still not getting the list to show.  I've added a link to the way I set up kali to run on my computer maybe it'll help

https://thehackernews.com/2018/03/kali-linux-hacking-windows.html

Comment: @depression_vortex . . . I edited the answer I provided and the answer is likely in the first statement . . . "*The Kali Linux OS instance you are running either does not have any processes listening on any network ports, or it has no network adapter/NIC available to use to listen for any protocols.*". Either the network is unavailable or nothing is listening. Please see the full answer though for further detail and how to confirm the issue. If you are running an VM, then be sure the network is activated and the machine can get an IP via DHCP or configure manually if needed.

Comment: I suspect this is your issue versus an anomalous or erroneous `netstat` output.

Comment: @depression_vortex Did you ever get a chance to look over the latest answer edit/update I've provided? Just curious of the results if so or current status.